# Проблема с Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php

Добрый вечер! Есть такой код:

```
<?php
$start_url = "http://vk.com";
$urls = array();
function parse_links($url){
global $urls;
$page = file_get_html($url);
$links = $page->find('a');
for($counter=0;$counter<count($links);$counter++){
array_push($urls,$links[$counter]->href);
}
unset($links);
unset($page);
return 0;
}
parse_links($start_url);
?>
```

Выдает ошибку:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /var/www/html/parser/parser.php on line 7

Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перевод ошибки "Вызываешь метод объекта 'find()' у не объекта".
Функция `file_get_html()` не возвращает объект, хотя, видимо, должна.
P. S. Глобальные переменные - зло!
P. P. S. Отформатируй код, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Посоветую использовать PHPQuery, вот вводная статья на хабре:

http://habrahabr.ru/post/69149/

Сам пользовался Simple HTML DOM, но иногда она без причины падала, невозможно было понять, в чем дело, т.к. она самостоятельно строит DOM, а этим она в корне отличается от аналогичных инструментов, т.к. все остальные работают с XPath.

Плюс эта библиотека самая медленная из всех аналогов.

Выбирал между nokogiri(ruby) и PHPQuery.